# css centered div

Tags: css, html

I have a centered div on my site, using a fixed width and margin:0 auto;

All looks fine in IE, but on FF, for the pages with long content, only the top part of the div has the proper div color, and the rest has the body background color.

what I'm doing wrong?

many thx

Comment: Could you please post up your HTML and CSS code for us to analyse.

Comment: Is the overflowed content images or text?  Which version of FF is the behavior on?  Zeldman had a somewhat similar problem in FF3.5: http://www.zeldman.com/2009/07/08/firefox-forces-red-background-flash/ and has opened a bug.

Comment: solved. many thx guys

i was using min-height and padding-bottom. this combination has give me some headaches.
many thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to tell, but my bet is that you've set the div height to %100, which means 100% of the viewport.

It will not stretch beyond that, even if the content is long enough. This is the correct behaviour.

To make it the full scree height when there's not enough content, and go beyond the viewport height when there's more than enough content, you'll need to use two divs.

Here's an example I've hosted:

[Div height 100% fix](http://gamilis.com/div_height/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width (i.e:600px) and height of the div you can use the following.
I center divs in one direction using 3 parameters:

Horizontal:

```
<div class='hcnt'>Some H Centered Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hcnt{
 left-margin:50%;
 width:600px;
 left:-300px;
}
```

Vertical:

```
<div class='vcnt'>Some V Centered Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vcnt{
     top-margin:50%;
     height:400px;
     top:-200px;
    }
```

Both:

```
<div class='hcnt vcnt'>Some completely Centered Text</div>
```